# MATLAB where are stored the F and p values when using fitlm

Tags: matlab, statistics

I'm using [fitlm](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitlm.html) to test a linear model:

```
mdl = fitlm(tbl,'GPA ~ 1 + HSRANK + SATV + SATM')
```

When using the function `disp(mdl)`, the following output appears:
[image]

My question is, where are stored the *F-statistic vs. constand model* and the *p-value*? I suppose they should be stored in the the *mdl* lineal model, but I can't find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common test statistics are available from within *LinearModel object*, but this is *not* the case for the F-statistic. Rather you can access it with [coefTest](http://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel.coeftest.html) or for a more elaborate view [anova](http://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel.anova.html).

Let us have a look at this reproducible example (a classic from MathWorks):

```
% Load some standard data 
load imports-85
ds = dataset(X(:,7),X(:,8),X(:,9),X(:,15),'Varnames',{'curb_weight','engine_size','bore','price'});
mdl = fitlm(ds,'price~curb_weight+engine_size+bore')

% Show
fit
```

[image]

Now use `coefTest` for your specific question:

```
[p,F] = coefTest(mdl)

% Output
% p =
%    1.1416e-47
% F =
%    135.5791
```

Also see what MathWorks writes about [Assess Fit of Model Using F-statistic](http://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/f-statistic-and-t-statistic.html).